# How do I log debugging messages of all cURL internal function calls to stdout?

Tags: c, curl, logging, stdout

I am working on an embedded device which uses cURL library for communication with other networking devices. I came across this:

**CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, long onoff);**

But it seems to be in particular context but I want it enable it globally, irrespective of the curl handle. Also I found this while searching in lib/sendf.h

**#define infof(...)  Curl_nop_stmt**

But I'm not able to get how to enable/use it.
I just need that all internal logs from cURL library are printed out to stdout using a single declaration.